# Скругление кнопки

Tags: qt, qt5, qt4, qss

Как скруглить кнопку `QPushButton`?
Нужно только скругление и больше ничего.

Comment: Вы уже как-то пробовали решить эту задачу?

Comment: да. ui->pushButton->setStyleSheet("    background-color: ;"
                                    "border-radius: 15px;"
                                    ); так скругляется. но мне дужно без
 "    background-color: ;"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12734319/change-rectangular-qt-button-to-round